# Is there anyway I can check whether part of a string in python is somewhere in another string? (beginner)

Tags: python

Let's say we have a string 'abc' and another string 'bcd'. If I do 'abc' in 'bcd' it will return false. I want to say 'if there is a character of 'abc' in the string 'bcd' than return true. (python)
edit: thank you for the spelling changes. It makes me feel dumb. They were typos though.

I have tried iterating through the string using for loops, but this is clunky and I am assuming it is not good practice. Anyway I couldn't make it flexible enough for my needs.

```
 import random
 symb1 = random.choice('abc@') # I am trying to test if it chose AL one 
 # symbol
 symb2 = random.choice('abc!')
 mystring = (symb1+symb2) #lets say mystring is 'a!'
 if mystring in '@!' # I want to test here somehow if part of mystring is 
 # in @!
```

I want it to output true, and the output is false. I understand why, I just need help creating a way to test for the symbol in mystring

Comment: if mystring in '@!' do somthing

Comment: yes I got that, but it is not for my use case

Comment: then you need to loop over you string elements and check if any of them is in another string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use list comprehensions.
Example;

```
>>> a = 'abc'
>>> b = 'bcd'
>>> [letter for letter in a if letter in b]  # list comprehensions
['b', 'c']
>>> any(letter for letter in a if letter in b)  # generator expression
True
```

> as mentioned by @asikorski; change to use generator expression so the loop stops on the first match.

Comment: This one can be even better if list comprehension is replaced with a generator expression, because there's no need to create a list for `any()`. `any()` will keep on iterating over a given iterable up to the first element that evaluates to `True`.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate one of the Strings while doing `in` checks:

```
any(c in "@!" for c in mystring)
```

"Is there any c from mystring in '@!'?"

Comment: This one is better than the accepted one, because uses a generator instead of list comprehension for `any`'s argument.

Comment: @asikorski While I agree that creating a whole list for `any` is wasteful, so is using `in` on a String. We were both going for simple solutions over efficient ones.

Answer (score 0):

Okay the comprehensions made more sense but I decided to do a more expanded for loop. I found a way to make it less terrible. I'm just teaching python to a friend and I want him to be able to read the code more easily. here's the section of code in the program.

```
def punc():
    characters = int(input('How long would you like your password to be? : '))
    passlist = []
    for x in range(characters):
        add = random.choice(string.ascii_letters + '@@@@@$$$$$~~~~!!!!!?????')
        passlist.append(add)
    l = []
    for x in passlist:
        if x in ['@','$','~','!','?']:
            l.append(0)
    if len(l) == 0:
        punc()
    else:
        print(''.join(passlist))
```

Comment: I'll just point out that the list on the right side of the `in` should be a set. Lists are expensive to do `in` checks on. I didn't mention it in my answer because I was trying to be brief. Linear membership lookups should be avoided whenever possible. And I'll note too that if you don't care about performance, a string could have been instead of a list like you used here. Strings can be iterated like lists.

Answer (score 0):

There are few solutions:

- the best one (both effective and *pythonic*):

```
if any(char in 'bcd' for char in 'abc'):
    ...
```

Uses generator + built-in [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any). It does not have to create a list with list comprehension and doesn't waste time to gather all the letters that are in both of strings, so it's memory effective.

- the boring one (~ C style):

```
def check_letters(word1, word2):
    for char in word1:
        if char in word2:
            return True
    reeturn False

if check_letters('abc', 'bcd'):
    ...
```

Quite obvious.

- the fancy one:

```
if set(list('abc')) & set(list('bcd')):
    ...
```

This one uses some *tricks*. `list` converts string to a list of letters, `set` creates a set of letters from the list. Then intersetion of two sets is created with `&` operator and `if`'s condition evaluates to `True` if there's any element in the intersection. 
It's not very effective, though; it has to create two lists and two sets.